# Edit iPhone Music ID3 Tags From App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I'd like to develop an iOS app that fixes tags in the user's music library using MusicBrainz. I haven't been able to find anything in the official SDK to facilitate the changing of ID3 tags for the song library, so I'm wondering if I missed something. Or does Apple even allow an app to behave like this? Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well , as you know , Apple is pretty strict when it comes to messing up with their data. 
iPod library can only be altered via iTunes syncing or iTunes downloading.

I hope they will give us programmers ways to (at least) create playlists , but until then , you could only accomplish that by jailbreaking and using private API's.

Comment: I was afraid someone would say that. Oh well. Thanks for saving me the headache of rejection!